Repair Scratch on Tesla Model 3 Front Bumper
My Tesla Model 3 recently incurred a scratch — someone scraped it with something, leaving a small but noticeable mark. I've attached some pictures for reference.
I reached out to a repair shop for an estimate, and they quoted around $600 USD, which seems steep to me.
Any recommendations for cost-effective repair options? DIY or professional?






It is very easy to turn a small blemish into a massive blemish on car body work if you are not highly experienced.
In one of your photos it looks like there is a small amount of plastic sticking out from the scratch.  If so, carefully cut this off using a very sharp blade, don't use sandpaper.

Then get a paint pen of the correct colour for the car, clean the area, then dab some paint on the scratch like in this video.
Take your time adding a little paint at a time and let it dry.  If you rush this you will make a mess.
Don't even think about spray paint and trying to get a perfect finish.  That is why the repair shop wanted so much money, it is not an easy job.


I would say your solution is probably the cheapest/easiest way to "fix" the issue. One other thing about the front bumper, while I've never dealt with a Tesla, I'll assume it is just like most other newer cars, that it has parking sensors in the bumper. In order to do this right, you'd really need to take the bumper off of the vehicle, which means you could potentially mess up the calibration on the sensors, which may incur more cost. The original quote to the OP may have included for that as well.

This is very helpful. Thank you very, very much!
